# Small file copy takes seconds in File Explorer, Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, copy

If I open My Documents in File Explorer and copy a 600kB text file, it takes 2-3 seconds.

I remember it being faster in the past and really in a virtual machine on the same PC, running Windows 7, the same operation takes less than half a second, it is almost instantaneous.

What I do:

- open File Explorer
- go to a subfolder in My Documents
- select the TXT file
- press ctrl-C
- press ctrl-V

Doing the same using COPY in command line is super fast, so maybe it is just a display issue. Still annoying, as it breaks the work flow.

OS is Windows 10 Pro 64 bit ver 1909
storage is SSD (even a HDD should not be so slow)

PS: One non-standard setting I have is *Launch Folder Windows in a Separate Process*. I'll try without it...

PPS: I tried other computers with Windows 10 and they don't have this issue, must be specific to this one. Maybe the AV software. I'll try to turn things off, restore default settings...

PPPS: I turned off  *Launch Folder Windows in a Separate Process* and later restarted (Windows update...) and the issue is gone. If it stays so, I'll write this as an answer.

Comment: How many files are in your target destination?

Comment: @Seth 16 files and 6 folders.

Comment: Sometimes, using copy from Explorer, Windows tries to access other drives, though they're not needed for the copy. E.G., if *Documents* is on an external HDD, and *Downloads* on the internal SSD, copying from one folder to another in *Downloads* sometimes causes the external HDD to activate though it's not used in the operation. Is that the cause of the issue?

Comment: I don't have external drives. Just an internal SSD and HDD.

Comment: What columns does your explorer display? If you are showing extended attributes, it has to reread all files in the directory. To verify, remove all extra columns.

Comment: @Aganju the standard: Name,Date modified,Type,Size ; The same problem happens in other maps too, like C:\test. Even with small files (TXT or other type).